# How can I mark a specific region on a 3d graph using matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph

For an assignment, I've had to create a 3d graph of surface temperature, T, of the Earth vs Albedo, A, and Emissivity, Epsilon. The second part of the assignment asks me to mark on my graph the region where Temperature is 270-300.

How do I go about doing this?
I've tried a couple of methods, mainly trying to overlay another graph onto the first but I cannot get that to work.

Here is my code for the assignment.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import cm
from matplotlib.ticker import LinearLocator

# Graph of Temperature vs Emissivity
Sigma=5.67e-8
A=0.29
Epsilon=np.arange(0,1,0.02) #atmosphereic emissivity
Fo=1367#flux from sun
do=1
d=1
F=Fo*((do/d)**2)
T_Earth=(((1-A)*F)/(4*Sigma*(1-(1/2*Epsilon))))**(1/4)
#print("The temperature of the Earth is {:.2f}".format(T_Earth))
# plt.scatter(Epsilon,T_Earth)
# plt.savefig("Emissivity")


# Graph of Temperature vs Albedo
A1=np.arange(0,1,0.02)
Epsilon1=0.76 #atmosphereic emissivity
Fo=1367#flux from sun
do=1
d=1
F=Fo*((do/d)**2)
T_Earth1=(((1-A1)*F)/(4*Sigma*(1-(1/2*Epsilon1))))**(1/4)
#print("The temperature of the Earth is {:.2f}".format(T_Earth))
# plt.scatter(A1,T_Earth1)
# plt.savefig("Albedo")

#plt.style.use("_mpl-gallery")
#3D Graph
A2=np.arange(0,1,0.01)
Epsilon2=np.arange(0,1,0.01)
# for A2 in np.arange(0,0.84,0.01)):
#   Epsilon3=np.arange(0,1,0.01)
# for Epsilon4 in np.arange(0,1,0.01):
#   A2=np.arange(0,0.84,0.01)



A2, Epsilon2 = np.meshgrid(A2, Epsilon2)
T_Earth2=(((1-A2)*F)/(4*Sigma*(1-(1/2*Epsilon2))))**(1/4)
fig, ax=plt.subplots(subplot_kw={"projection": "3d"})
surf=ax.plot_surface(A2,Epsilon2, T_Earth2, vmin=T_Earth2.min()*2, cmap=cm.coolwarm, ec="gray", lw=0.2)
plt.colorbar(surf)
# ax.set(xticklabels=[], yticklabels=[], zticklabels=[])
ax.set_xlabel('A')
ax.set_ylabel('E')
ax.set_zlabel('T')

plt.savefig("3D")




# Make data
X = np.arange(-3, 3, 0.25)
Y = np.arange(-3, 3, 0.25)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(X, Y)
R = np.sqrt(X**2 + Y**2)
Z = np.sin(R)

# Plot the surface
fig, ax = plt.subplots(subplot_kw={"projection": "3d"})
ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, vmin=Z.min() * 2, cmap=cm.viridis)

ax.set(xticklabels=[],
       yticklabels=[],
       zticklabels=[])

X1 = np.arange(-5, 5, 0.25)
Y1 = np.arange(-5, 5, 0.25)
X1, Y1 = np.meshgrid(X1, Y1)
R1 = np.sqrt(X1**2 + Y1**2)
Z1 = np.sin(R1)

# Plot the surface
ax.plot_surface(X1, Y1, Z1, cmap=cm.Blues)
ax.set(xticklabels=[], yticklabels=[], zticklabels=[])
plt.savefig("test2")
```

This just makes the second graph I plot completely replace the first and not make them overlap. Rather than having parts of 1 visible past the edges of the other.

Comment: Remove the second `fig, ax = plt.subplots()`. The plot will be on the same axes.

Comment: I tried that and it hasn't worked. The section of code I'm trying to plot 2 at once with is everything down from "#Make Data# but this is still only plotting one of them.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to plot everything together in one single plot, you need one set of `figure` and `ax` only. In your code, the first set of figure and axis is closed when the second set is created, thus, the previously plotted features are gone and you get the features that are plotted after the creation of the new figure/axis.

Here is a modified code and the output that shows all of the features together in a single plot.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import cm
from matplotlib.ticker import LinearLocator

# Graph of Temperature vs Emissivity
Sigma=5.67e-8
A=0.29
Epsilon=np.arange(0,1,0.02) #atmosphereic emissivity
Fo=1367#flux from sun
do=1
d=1
F=Fo*((do/d)**2)
T_Earth=(((1-A)*F)/(4*Sigma*(1-(1/2*Epsilon))))**(1/4)

# Graph of Temperature vs Albedo
A1=np.arange(0,1,0.02)
Epsilon1=0.76 #atmosphereic emissivity
Fo=1367#flux from sun
do=1
d=1
F=Fo*((do/d)**2)
T_Earth1=(((1-A1)*F)/(4*Sigma*(1-(1/2*Epsilon1))))**(1/4)

#3D Graph
A2=np.arange(0,1,0.01)
Epsilon2=np.arange(0,1,0.01)

A2, Epsilon2 = np.meshgrid(A2, Epsilon2)
T_Earth2=(((1-A2)*F)/(4*Sigma*(1-(1/2*Epsilon2))))**(1/4)
fig, ax=plt.subplots(subplot_kw={"projection": "3d"})
surf=ax.plot_surface(A2,Epsilon2, T_Earth2, vmin=T_Earth2.min()*2, cmap=cm.coolwarm, ec="gray", lw=0.2)
cb = plt.colorbar(surf, shrink=0.65)

# ax.set(xticklabels=[], yticklabels=[], zticklabels=[])
ax.set_xlabel('A')
ax.set_ylabel('E')
ax.set_zlabel('T')

# Make data
X = np.arange(-3, 3, 0.25)
Y = np.arange(-3, 3, 0.25)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(X, Y)
R = np.sqrt(X**2 + Y**2)
Z = np.sin(R)

# Plot the surface on the same figure
# Just go ahead and plot

# Dont need this line:-
# fig, ax = plt.subplots(subplot_kw={"projection": "3d"})  # <------------ remove
ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, vmin=Z.min() * 2, cmap=cm.viridis)

ax.set(xticklabels=[],
       yticklabels=[],
       zticklabels=[])

X1 = np.arange(-5, 5, 0.25)
Y1 = np.arange(-5, 5, 0.25)
X1, Y1 = np.meshgrid(X1, Y1)
R1 = np.sqrt(X1**2 + Y1**2)
Z1 = 50*np.sin(R1)  # <----- Scale it for visualization

# Plot the surface
ax.plot_surface(X1, Y1, Z1, cmap=cm.Blues, alpha=0.5)
ax.set(xticklabels=[], yticklabels=[], zticklabels=[])
plt.show()
```

[image: 3d]